# Does this metric induce the same topology as the euclidean does?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I do not really know how to solve this one. Id be grateful for some tips on how to solve it

Here is the question:
1) Decide if the given Metric d in  $\mathbb{R^2} $   induces  the same Topology as the Euclidean metric does.
2) Does d come from a Norm in  $\mathbb{R^2} $ and if so, does the norm come from a Scalar product?

[image]

Comment: Well, $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$ means that $(0,0)$, $\ (x_1,y_1)$, $\ (x_2,y_2)$ are collinear.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** (1) What is, for example, the open ball of radius $1$ around $(1,0)$ accourding to your metric? Is this set open according to the Euclidean topology?

(2) If the metric comes from a norm, then the translation of a ball is itself a ball.